# How to write a program just using two string methods?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program for my homework that computes a word and a sentence's same character numbers at same indexes.

The point is the user writes a sentence and a word and the program computes same chars from same indexes and prints number of it. But if word is shorter than sentence I have to slide word one whitespace to right and repeat until the length of the word exceeds the length of the sentence.

And I am allowed to use just length and charAt as string methods. I cannot find the best way to write, I am stuck.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            // asking a sentence from user
            System.out.println("Lütfen bir cümle giriniz."); 
            String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();

            //asking a word from user 
            System.out.println("Lütfen bir kelime giriniz."); 
            String word = keyboard.next();

            int sentenceLength = sentence.length();
            int wordLength = word.length();

            for (wordLength = 1; wordLength <= sentenceLength; wordLength++);

            word.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it by using while.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static final void main(String args[])
    {
        String word, sent;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("sent->");
        sent=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("word->");
        word=sc.nextLine();
        while(word.length()<sent.length())
            word = word + ' ';
    }
}
```